# Run a method in initialize after class has been called

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want the results of the ***method_test()*** to to be stored in variable ***a***. So that I access it outside my class

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        a = method()

    def method_test():
        return "working"


check = test
print(check.a)
```

Comment: `self.a = method_test()`?

Comment: type object 'test' has no attribute 'a' @meowgoesthedog I get an error

Comment: Did you mean `check = test` (the type object) or `check = test()` (an instance)? The latter should work.

Comment: 'method_test' is not defined @meowgoesthedog

Comment: See `yatu`'s answer. Your code has too many mistakes to debug one comment at a time.

Comment: Use, `self.a = test.method_test()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it as an attribute, which can be done with `self.a`:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = test.method_test()

    def method_test():
        return "working"

check = test()
print(check.a)
#working
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
class test:
     def __init__(self):
             self.a = self.method_test()
     def method_test(self):
             return "working"
check = test()
print (check.a)
```